# How to split .nano_history file to exclude sudo uses?

Tags: configuration, sudo, linux

I often use `nano` for quick edits over ssh. If I combine this with `sudo` though my `.nano_history` file becomes unreadable for non-`sudo` editing. I end getting the following warnings:

```
Error reading /home/user-name/.nano_history: Permission denied
```

Is there any way of spitting the history file such that I can still access my non-`sudo` history?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `sudo` only raises your privileges but keeps the old environment (not all, but at least `$HOME` is kept). So it isn't exactly possible to do what you want, without at least messing with bash aliases...

The easiest way to get rid of this problem is **simply `chown` the existing history files to your own user**. Then nano will work fine both as you and as root. *(History files are only appended to; they're never deleted automatically and so the ownership will stay.)*

Answer (score 0):

To avoid similar problems with other dotfiles, I'd recommend using sudo to login as the superuser, rather than just grant privileges to your current user:

```
sudo su -
```

Note some shops frown on the use of a superuser, preferring RBAC schemes, but based on the way you are using sudo I'm guessing yours isn't one of them.

Comment: There's `sudo -i` for that already, why use `su`?

Comment: I thought this was just old habit, but it isn't: "sudo -i" doesn't evaluate any startup scripts (.login etc.) so you will typically end up with a PATH excluding /sbin and /usr/sbin and similar. "sudo su -" gives you exactly what you would get if you had logged in directly as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-H` switch with sudo.  That option sets the *$HOME* environment variable to the home directory of the target user, typically */root*.   `sudo -H nano <file>` will use root's *.nano_history* file instead of your own.